# Can I partial compile a template function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function to determine whether a template type is pointer.

```
template<class T>
struct is_pointer_struct { static const bool value = false; };

template<class T>
struct is_pointer_struct<T*> { static const bool value = true; };

template<class T>
bool is_pointer(T &var) {
    return is_pointer_struct<T>::value;
}
```

And I have a initialize function.

```
template<class T>
void initialize(T &val) {
    if (is_pointer(val))
        val = NULL;
    else
        val = T();
}
```

Obviously, when `T` is `string`, this code can't be compiled. Is there a way that compile `val = NULL` when `T` is pointer type and compile `val = T()` when `T` is not a pointer type?

Comment: You can initialize it using list initialization syntax `val = T{};`. This will initialize pointers to nullptr, integral types and other POD types to 0 and non POD types using default constructor. And you can do it in C++11.

Comment: Why would `val = T()` not work with pointers, too???

Comment: @Aconcagua you can imagine this pointer is `const char *`

Comment: @Howard That would still produce a null pointer... Problem would be `char* const`, as then the pointer itself is const - but then *any* variant (in question or in the answers) would fail. If you introduced a specialisation or an overload for const pointers (using const_cast inside), you get UB if you pass a truely constant pointer to the function...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your particular case you could just use uniform initialization, as [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt) said:

```
val = T{};
```

Also, the Standard Library provides [`std::is_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer).

---

As an answer to the more general question *"how do I branch at compile-time?"*:

- In C++17, all you have to do  is change your `if(...)` to `if constexpr(...)`:

  ```
  template<class T>
  void initialize(T &val) {
      if constexpr(is_pointer(val))
          val = nullptr;
      else
          val = T();
  }
  ```
- In C++14, you [can implement your own `static_if`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k).
- In C++03/11, you could use tag dispatching:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  void initialize_impl(std::true_type /* pointer */, T& val)
  {
      val = NULL;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void initialize_impl(std::false_type /* non-pointer */, T& val)
  {
      val = T();
  }

  template<class T>
  void initialize(T &val) { initialize_impl(std::is_pointer<T>{}, val); }
  ```

Comment: Can I make it in c++11?

Comment: Should be: `val = T{}` - actually, no need for: `val = T()` works absolutely fine with pointers, too, and is pre-C++11 compatible...

Comment: I would have thought that the OP's `is_pointer` function would have to marked `constexpr` to be used in `if constexpr`.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky or anything, but this `NULL` instead of `nullptr` really makes me cringe, especially in C++17 example. Anyway, great answer.

Answer (score 6):

The right way to do the things in your case is to use uniform initialization, as it is mentioned.

As an option, you might make use of *SFINAE* based on your type trait so the necessary template will be instantiated (here is a *C++ 11* way to do that):

```
template<class T>
auto initialize(T &val) ->
    typename std::enable_if<is_pointer_struct<T>::value>::type {
        val = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
auto initialize(T &val) ->
    typename std::enable_if<!is_pointer_struct<T>::value>::type {
        val = T();
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go, imho

Answer (score 6):

Classic solution, not even requiring C++11 features: Simple overloads:

```
template<class T>
void initialize(T& val)
{
    val = T();
}
template<class T>
void initialize(T*& val)
{
    val = NULL;
}
```

However, the first overload (in the specific case) covers pointers too, so the second one actually is obsolete.

Disregarding obsolescence, I would prefer `nullptr` keyword over `NULL` macro (though losing pre-C++11 compatibility again).